# Removing L298N Jumpers & Motors stop

Tags: arduino, pins, motordriver

I've removed all jumper connecting the ENA pin with the 5V pin, and used a female-to-male jumper wire to connect the ENA pin to my breadboard (being powered by 12V from the arduino)-- however, now the wheel doesn't move anymore. If I re-connect the jumper, the wheel moves at max speed. I made sure that my pins were going into the PMW enabled slots in the arduino (~9). Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Comment: I don't use wheels - I use tank tracks and I never use L298Ns

Comment: @Andyaka Ok....... ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the issue was connecting the Vin in my arduino with the 5V in the L298N!